# I dentification of training phrases for Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to build a chatbot using Google Dialogflow. I have a set of 100 utterances with me for different Intents. How can I select the training phrases out of this 100 utterance list? Is there any rule to select the unique patterns from the list on the basis of entity pattern or unique paraphrase?

It would be very helpful if you could share the answer here.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit what exactly do you want, with some kind of examples? Did you check [Train a chatbot intent](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/building-chatbot-agent-dialogflow#train_a_chatbot_intent) documentation? Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Training phrases are example phrases for what end-users might type or say, referred to as end-user expressions. For each intent, you create many training phrases. When an end-user expression resembles one of these phrases, Dialogflow matches the intent.

For example, the training phrase "I want pizza" trains your agent to recognize end-user expressions that are similar to that phrase, like "Get a pizza" or "Order pizza".

**You don't have to define every possible example, because Dialogflow's built-in machine learning expands on your list with other, similar phrases. You should create at least 10-20 (depending on complexity of intent) training phrases and try to include more unique training phrases which are relevant to that specific Intent**, so your agent can recognize a variety of end-user expressions.

Reference link :https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-training-phrases